# Problem with a transformation from a char array to a string in C#, if the array has two entries which are the same

Tags: c#, arrays, string

First, excuse me for my poor english.
I'm fairly new to this website and to programming in general, but I've made some researchs to find a solution for this problem.

I'm making a little program which takes a string as an input, and returns the same string except the vowels.

My method is to transform each word of the string to a char array, to remove the vowels using array.Except, and to transform the array to a string.

The problem is that when a word contain two letters which are the same, the final string contains only one.

For example, "losers" become "lsr" instead of "lsrs".

Can you help me with that?

My code is shown below:

```
string str = "Sample phrase to test";
string[] words;
words = str.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int compteurRetourne;
for(compteurRetourne = 0; compteurRetourne < words.Length; compteurRetourne++)
{
        char[] arr = words[compteurRetourne].ToCharArray();
        arr = arr.Except(new List<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' }).ToArray();
        words[compteurRetourne] = new string(arr);
}           
str = string.Join(" ", words);
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: [`IEnumerable<T>.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8) produces a set difference, that's why your resulting array doesn't have duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps a lot! Can you tell me if there is another method to remove the vowels?

Comment: `arr.Where(ch => !vowels.Contains(ch))`